# Как перебрать массив чтобы первое значение не было пустым?

Tags: php, парсер, api

Использую такой вариант перебора

```
<?php
foreach($b['response']['wall'] as $value) : 
$text = strip_tags ($value['text']); 
?>

<textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><? echo $text; ?></textarea> 

<? 
endforeach;
?>
```

первое значение выводит пустым, если способ аккуратно перебрать массив без этой проблемы?

Comment: `if (!$value) { continue; }` добавьте эту строку в тело цикла

Comment: исправьте сам масив, удалите пустые елементы, зачем писать костыли?

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, судя по наличию слова `response`, можно предположить, что массив со всеми своими пустыми элементами был откуда-то получен. Если обработать его надо только в одном месте, то вариант, предложенный Эдуардом, будет менее ресурсозатратным.

Comment: но перед проходом можно сделать array_filer() что будет намного легче понять потом, чем это условие. И еще проверка каждого елемента вряд ли будет быстрее оптимиризованой функции array_filer(). Как говорят if это очень затратно

Comment: как вариант еще array_shift(), а допольнительные условие в теле цыкла, мне потом сложно читать. в цыкле должна быть только логика обработки, а не еще логика выборки самых елементов

Comment: хорошо, я проверю что будет работать быстрее foreach c if или array_filter

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, очень затратно - это предварительно прогонять массив через array_filter. Тут даже проверять не надо. Как по вашему работает эта функция?

Comment: да, он будет работать более медленно http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/ . Зато избавит от лишней логики внутри цыкла

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, кажется, вы не сталкивались с высоконагруженными системами. Жертвовать производительностью (а разница в два раза и более) ради *избавления от лишней логики в цикле* - это в корне неправильный подход.

Comment: да, здесь я ошибся. Попробую найти тот момент который нашел в одной библиотеке где избавлялись от if c помощью `$a || $a = foo();`

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо за ответ, все равно первый элемент пустой. Вот мой код:

foreach($b['response']['wall'] as $value) :
$text = strip_tags ($value['text']); 

 <textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><? echo $text; ?></textarea>

<?
endforeach;?>

Comment: @MykolaVeriga Подскажите как это можно решить с помощью  array_filer()?

Comment: @Дмитрий [Смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/285804ce805d9a2d688c59bb844b3da8f7e48281)

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо!